First associate this domain with either a Commerce LWR site, or a LWR site that's hosted on Experience Delivery error
We are trying to add a new Custom URL for the deployed domain since customer request us to implement path redirection but we are facing an error saying that
First associate this domain with either a Commerce LWR site, or a LWR site that's hosted on Experience Delivery


How can we avoid or fix this error? Is there any solution or workaround?

The problem is the domain we configured, customer.site.com,

has the option enabled and grayed out
[x] Use the Salesforce CDN for Commerce LWR sites or sites hosted on Experience Delivery
which defines CDN partner as CloudFlare while we should have chosen Akamai.
This is optional checkbox on the original configuration

which we can't edit after the site is live.
This documentation has a note
Note
Note If you’re using a custom domain that has enabled the Salesforce CDN with the partner Cloudflare, then the first site you associate it with has to be either a Commerce LWR site or a site hosted on Experience Delivery.

We were enabled to setup this domain with Aura site but we are now not able to add any additional Custom URL
